Why is my GLB file from Blender not casting shadows in Three JS? (specifically in react three fiber)
I exported a GLB file from blender but when I import it into three js, it does not cast any shadows. I have made sure that my light has castShadow set to true, my ground has receiveShadow set to true, and I loop through all the children of my gltf scene and make sure they have castShadow set to true as well. I also made sure that my canvas has the shadows tag as well.
<Canvas shadows>...</Canvas>.
const { nodes, scene, animations } = useGLTF(
    "../../assets/full.glb",
) as GLTFResult;

useEffect(() => {
    scene.traverse((child) => {
        if (child.isMesh) child.castShadow = true;
    });
}, [scene]);

Does anyone have any idea why this would be casting shadows? I will provide my lights code and ground as well in case that helps.
<mesh
    rotation-x={-Math.PI / 2}
    position-y={-0.5}
    scale={new Vector3(FOV, FOV, FOV)}
    receiveShadow
>
    <circleGeometry />
    <meshPhongMaterial>
        <GradientTexture
            stops={[0, 0.7]}
            colors={["aquamarine", "white"]}
            width={1024}
            type={GradientType.Radial}
        />
    </meshPhongMaterial>
</mesh>

<ambientLight args={[0xffffff]} intensity={0.5} />
<spotLight
    position={[0, 2, 0]}
    intensity={5}
    ref={dirLight}
    castShadow
/>

